# Jenkins without icons

Tags: cloudbees

My instance is working fine but it's been a while since the icons were working. You can see it [here](https://xinco.ci.cloudbees.com/). I tried restarting the instance various times without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had green-balls plugin "1.12-h-1" plugin installed. This plugin is designed for eclipse hudson 3.0 and incompatible with jenkins. We (cloudbees) have noticed this issue and removed it from our update center in the meantime.